# Adding swagger UI for spring cloud gateway service

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, spring-cloud-gateway

I need help in adding swagger ui for my spring cloud gateway microservice.

My spring cloud gateway service is routing the request to another microservice which already has swagger ui enabled since it has a controller layer

But since my spring cloud gateway service doesn't have any @Controller class and all the routes are defined in a RouteConfig class which doesn't do much except routing the request to actual service